# Cannot convert a str to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have an issue with my code. I followed several topics referred to this topic, but I didn't found a answer to my question.

I am currently working on a forex forecasting project in python and my biggest issue right now is to convert a str to a datetime.

My str looks like this: `Feb 06, 2019`
For converting to datetime i made the following modifications:
     Lets assume that 'x' is my string:

```
 `x = x.replace(",","")` => Feb 06 2019
 `x = x.replace(" ", "-")` => Feb-06-2019`
```

The problem is when I try to convert into datetime

```
x = datetime.strtime(x,'%m-%d-%Y') => time data 'Feb-06-2019' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'
```

I know maybe it's a dumb question but I can't really get the problem and it's getting frustrating.
Thank you in advance for answering.

I have a

Comment: what about using format that matches your input data?

Comment: `Feb` doesn't match `%m`. Break the problem down until you find the wrong format

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%b` is for three-char month names.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3.6, I was able to do it with **datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%b-%d-%Y')**.

Resulted in **2019-02-06 00:00:00**.